# JFreeChart grid line Color

Tags: java, colors, charts, jfreechart, gridlines

I am making a `BarChart` with `JFreeChart` in java. The default code makes a chart with dashed grid lines. As far as I can see, here is the only part of the code that deals with the gridlines.

```
   final CategoryPlot plot = chart1.getCategoryPlot();
                    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
                    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.black);
                    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.black);
```

How would I edit this/add code to this so the grid lines are a solid color? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [CategoryPlot](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CategoryPlot.html) class, you will find the [setDomainGridlineStroke()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CategoryPlot.html#setDomainGridlineStroke%28java.awt.Stroke%29) method - it let's you specify the line style for the x-axis gridlines.  The [setRangeGridlineStroke()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CategoryPlot.html#setRangeGridlineStroke%28java.awt.Stroke%29) method will do the same for the y-axis gridlines.

Comment: the same goes for `XYPlot`